# Laravel model eager loading condition from other model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing booking site using Laravel.
And I have a difficult problem in getting data from Laravel model.

[image]

in image, hauls and bids is 1:1, 
hauls and vehicle is n:n via haul_vehicle,
bids and driver is 1:n

I want to get data like this

```
    `$res = Haul::with('vehicles')
        ->with('bids')
        ->with('bids.driver')
        ->find(1);
```

`

but I want to get data using condition vehicles.driver_id = bids.driver_id

help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand clearly what you want to do, but you can customize the relationship query using anonymous function e.g.:-

```
    $res = Haul::with([
        "vehicles" => function ($query) {
            //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THE QUERY HERE
            //e.g
            return $query->where("value", ">", "100");
        },
        'bids',
        'bids.driver'
    ])->find(1);
```